# How to prevent OpenOffice from running file recovery every time at startup?

Tags: windows, openoffice

Whenever I start my computer and start OpenOffice, the file recovery option is always displayed.
How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 1):

Add to your OpenOffice starting command the option `-norestore`.

Options to start OpenOffice:

```
-minimized    keep startup bitmap minimized.
-invisible    no startup screen, no default document and no UI.
-norestore    suppress restart/restore after fatal errors.
-quickstart   starts the quickstart service (only available on windows and OS/2 platform)
-nologo       don't show startup screen.
-nolockcheck  don't check for remote instances using the installation
-nodefault    don't start with an empty document
-headless     like invisible but no userinteraction at all.
-help/-h/-?   show this message and exit.
-writer       create new text document.
-calc         create new spreadsheet document.
-draw         create new drawing.
-impress      create new presentation.
-base         create new database.
-math         create new formula.
-global       create new global document.
-web          create new HTML document.
-o            open documents regardless whether they are templates or not.
-n            always open documents as new files (use as template).

-display <display>
      Specify X-Display to use in Unix/X11 versions.
-p <documents...>
      print the specified documents on the default printer.
-pt <printer> <documents...>
      print the specified documents on the specified printer.
-view <documents...>
      open the specified documents in viewer-(readonly-)mode.
-show <presentation>
      open the specified presentation and start it immediately
-accept=<accept-string>
      Specify an UNO connect-string to create an UNO acceptor through which
      other programs can connect to access the API
-unaccept=<accept-string>
      Close an acceptor that was created with -accept=<accept-string>
      Use -unnaccept=all to close all open acceptors
```

Remaining arguments will be treated as filenames or URLs of documents to open.